# React | Having trouble enacting state changes in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, frontend, react-component

I am coding a checkers web app and have set up user interaction by placing onclick functions on the components. I have two different components pieces and spaces. Ideally, the onclick functions are linked to methods in the parent component which interpret the state of the component being clicked and responds by returning data back to the component or a separate component. The issue is, I do not understand how to send data to child components from the parent following the mounting of said child component. I understand you can use props to initialize the state in a child component, but is there anyway I can update the child component from the parent following this initialization? I am new to react so I'm not exactly sure how inter component communication works quite yet.

Comment: Welcome to SO - please take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure you get the best support.

Comment: The react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) are a great place to start learning what React is, how it works, and how to design your UI with it. If you'd like more help here then please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example and specific details on a specifically scoped issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass update function to child, I hope this helps.

Parent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            something:""
        }
    }
    updateSomething = (anotherThing) => {
        this.setState({something:anotherThing})
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {/* we are passing updateSomething function in props*/}
            <ChildComponent updateSomething={(anotherThing)=>this.updateSomething(anotherThing)}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Child

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class ChildComponent extends Component {
    render() {
       
        return (
            <div>
                {/* we are using updateSomething function to update parents state*/}
                <button onClick={()=>this.props.updateSomething("anotherThing")}>Update Parents state</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```